Why were ticker tapes used in explosive tests?
After the final implosion test at Trinity Base Camp, Kistiakowsky
reads the ticker tape and shows it to Fuchs:

From my understanding, ticker tapes are typically used in stock markets.
Why were ticker tapes used in explosive tests?

Seismometer tape? Or just any sort of continual recording device from the era

@Valorum Script also says its ticker tape not Seismometer tape

yeah, but that's like calling something a biro

If you have the script, it might help other people to answer if you provide the section surrounding this part;  more context will probably be helpful.

The "ticker" in the name comes from the noise the printer makes.  Calling it "ticker tape" doesn't mean it can only be used to print financial data.  You wouldn't necessarily call it "seismometer tape" just because it contains data from a seismometer.  Putting "ticker" in the script tells us the kind of tape they used visually - i.e. long continuous thin strips.

@MichaelSeifert - I can confirm that the script is of no help whatsoever, and the scene doesn't exist in the source biography.

The tape does not look like the sort of punched tape used for computers and teletypes and is too narrow. But it seems to have a printed scale of some sort. This makes it more likely to be some simple sort of time-based recording trace. Which is exactly what the scientists would use for pressure, seismography, electrical signals etc. This is how much data was collected before data logging computers were invented.

Punched paper tape of various types was used to control many devices beginning in the 18th century and continuing into the 20th century.

Ticker tape was the earliest electrical dedicated financial communications medium, transmitting stock price information over telegraph lines, in use from around 1870 to 1970. It consisted of a paper strip that ran through a machine called a stock ticker, which printed abbreviated company names as alphabetic symbols followed by numeric stock transaction price and volume information. The term "ticker" came from the sound made by the machine as it printed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_tape
Valorum's suggestion that it might be a seismometer tape, or a tape from some other scientific recording instrument makes a lot of sense.
It is quite possible that scientists at the Trinity test used various instruments which recorded their data on paper tape.
I also thought of computer tape.
Old time computers used punch cards or used ticker tape like long thin pieces of paper which came out of slots.
I specifically remember an episode of Doctor Who, presumably from the 7th Season in 1970 with Jon Pertwee as the Doctor.   He was studying a long, narrow piece of paper coming from a slot in a computer.  That would have been an Earth computer used by UNIT and the UNIT stories were set in the contemporary 1970s - except when they were set in the 1980s, quite a contraction for fans.

A minicomputer, or colloquially mini, is a type of smaller general-purpose computer developed in the mid-1960s1 and sold at a much lower price than mainframe3 and mid-size computers from IBM and its direct competitors. In a 1970 survey, The New York Times suggested a consensus definition of a minicomputer as a machine costing less than US$25,000 (equivalent to $196,000 in 2023[4]), with an input-output device such as a teleprinter and at least four thousand words of memory, that is capable of running programs in a higher level language, such as Fortran or BASIC.[5]
The term "minicomputer" developed in the 1960s[7] to describe the smaller computers that became possible with the use of transistors and core memory technologies, minimal instructions sets and less expensive peripherals such as the ubiquitous Teletype Model 33 ASR.[6][8] They usually took up one or a few 19-inch rack cabinets, compared with the large mainframes that could fill a room.[9]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicomputer

When the first minicomputers were being released, most manufacturers turned to the existing mass-produced ASCII teleprinters (primarily the Teletype Model 33, capable of ten ASCII characters per second throughput) as a low-cost solution for keyboard input and printer output. The commonly specified Model 33 ASR included a paper tape punch/reader, where ASR stands for "Automatic Send/Receive" as opposed to the punchless/readerless KSR – Keyboard Send/Receive and RO – Receive Only models. As a side effect, punched tape became a popular medium for low-cost minicomputer data and program storage, and it was common to find a selection of tapes containing useful programs in most minicomputer installations. Faster optical readers were also common.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_tape#Minicomputers
Of course there weren't any minicomputers in the 1940s 20 years before they were invented.  But possibly the makers of Oppenheimer (2024) remembered scenes in old movies where paper tape with data came out of computers and was read by scientists, and figured that 1945 was so long ago that audiences would accept 1960s technology being used in 1940s scenes.
